# Foreign Key Creation issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

When I try to create these two tables I get:

> "SQL Error: ORA-00904: "COLLECTIBLENUM": invalid identifier"

I'm sure it's a noob error but I'm just not seeing it.  Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE Collectibles(
  CollectibleNum Number(10) NOT NULL,                            
CONSTRAINT collectibles_pk PRIMARY KEY(CollectibleNum)); 

Create table DiecastItems(
  DiecastName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,   
DiecastCopy NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,  
  DiecastScale VARCHAR2(25),  
  ColorScheme VARCHAR2(25),  
  DiecastYear NUMBER(4),  
  CONSTRAINT diecastItem_pk PRIMARY KEY(DiecastName, DiecastCopy),  
  CONSTRAINT diecastItem_Collectible_fk FOREIGN KEY(CollectibleNum) REFERENCES Collectibles(CollectibleNum));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add FK, you are linking a column *as a child* from the table you are creating, to its *parent* from the parent table. Hence, you need to provide the child column name, as well as the parent column name.

The general syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
);
```

Notice that the columns between `FOREIGN KEY` brackets, are from the table you are creating, while the columns betweeN `REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE`  are from the parent table.

You do not have a column called `CollectibleNum` in your`DiecastItems`. Hence, the following works fine by adding such a column:

```
CREATE TABLE collectibles 
  ( 
     collectiblenum NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT collectibles_pk PRIMARY KEY(collectiblenum) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE diecastitems 
  ( 
     diecastname    VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL, 
     diecastcopy    NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
     diecastscale   VARCHAR2(25), 
     colorscheme    VARCHAR2(25), 
     diecastyear    NUMBER(4), 
     collectiblenum NUMBER(10),   --added column
     CONSTRAINT diecastitem_pk PRIMARY KEY(diecastname, diecastcopy), 
     CONSTRAINT diecastitem_collectible_fk FOREIGN KEY(collectiblenum) 
     REFERENCES collectibles(collectiblenum) 
  );
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8be725)